# Python unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str

Tags: python, excel, wmi

I'm writing a short script where I plan on getting some information about the host PC and write it to an excel workbook. I'm still learning stuff so it's nothing fancy.
I get all the data I need and can write in most of the stuff. 
I can't seem to get one thing work though. 
When trying the below code:

```
hardwareSheet.write("B7", usage + "%")
```

I can print out the "usage" variable only but when I add +"%" I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

I'm using xlsxwriter library to crate and write excel.
hardwareSheet.write is a command allowing me to write data into sheet named hardware.
Here's how I got "usage" variable:

```
cpuInfo = wmi.Win32_Processor()[0]
usage = float(cpuInfo.LoadPercentage)
```

If I didn't parse cpuInfo.LoadPercentage to a float it would be a string.
I googled this and read that I need to parse the str into a float so I did so.Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: You can't add a string to a float. Does your program need to do arithmetic  on `usage`? If not, don't bother converting it to float.

Comment: Need to parse `usage` to a float for what purpose?

Comment: @PM 2Ring - Yes, I did some arithmetics on it but in a separate functions so I didn't have to parse it in a global variable. I got it now. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can't add floats and strings in python. `usage` is a float. `"%"` is a string.

you should do something like:

```
str(usage) + '%'
```

Comment: Ok, I just checked and I was wrong. "Usage" is an int. So I need to change it to a string, correct?

Comment: Ok, got it now. That was my problem, after changing it to a str it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is one more option to get the same output.

```
'{0}%'.format(usage)
```

Answer (score 0):

A cutting-edge solution using Python 3.6+ [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
hardwareSheet.write("B7", f'{usage}%')
```